# R - using intsvy package - pisa.reg.pv returning error ('a' must be a complex matrix)

Tags: r

I am using the **'intsvy'** package in R Studio to analyze PISA. I am actually replicating code from someone else, so really wondering why the following command does not work (when it works in the other persons coding):

```
R0 <- pisa.reg.pv(pvlabel="MATH", 
                  x="VIETNAM",
                  weight="W_FSTUWT",
                  data=DEVCON8a, export=FALSE)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in chol2inv(Qr$qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE]) : 
  'a' must be a complex matrix
```

I double checked that all variables are 'numeric':

```
class(DEVCON8a$W_FSTUWT)
#[1] "numeric"
class(DEVCON8a$VIETNAM)
#[1] "numeric"
class(DEVCON8a$PVxMATH) for the 5 different plausible values
#[1] "numeric"
```

"Vietnam" is just a dummy (numeric) I created within the data set. The data set is basically the original as downloaded from the PISA, filtered for 8 developing countries (hence DEVCON8, including Vietnam). All the previous coding is basically the same I am working off from the other person, for whom the 'pisa.reg.pv' is working perfectly fine. Could it have sth to do with a newer R version?

Thank you.

Comment: You could also try the `RALSA` package which has a graphical user interface: https://cran.r-project.org/package=RALSA For guides on how to use it, see here: http://ralsa.ineri.org/user-guide/

Answer (score -2):

Try upgrading R and try executing `update.packages()`.

If problem still persists, please post the data in your question so we can try to assist.